# spark sql query，java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I try to join 2 hive tables, omega and card， as follows：

table omega:

```
+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|pid   |enventid|card_id|count|name |
+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|111111|"sk"    |"pro"  |2    |"aaa"|
|222222|"sk"    |"pro"  |2    |"ddd"|
+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
```

table card:

```
+-------+---------+
|card_id|card_desc|
+-------+---------+
|"pro"  |"1|2|3"  | 
+-------+---------+
```

then I defined a udf:

```
val getListUdf = udf((raw: String) => raw.split("|"))
```

now，i try to join 2 tables with the defined udf:

```
omega.join(card, Seq("card_id"), "left_outer").withColumn("card_desc", getListUdf(col("card_desc")))
```

but, I got these errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:25)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
......
```

How should i solve it? Who can help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you feed nulls into your UDF which cause a nullpointer (call `split` on null). Try :

```
.withColumn("card_desc", 
            when(
              col("card_desc").isNotNull,
              getListUdf(col("card_desc"))
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are *joining both dataframes using `left-outer` join*, *there would be `null` values in `card_desc` column for the `rows` in omega dataframe which doesn't have matching `card_id` in card dataframe*. And when the `udf` function tries to *split null values, you get nullPointerException*.

I would recommend you to use the `split` *inbuilt function* which handles the `null` values as

```
omega.join(card, Seq("card_id"), "left_outer")
  .withColumn("card_desc", split(col("card_desc"), "\\|"))
```

*`split` function does exactly the same as you are doing with `udf` function.*

Or you can change your udf function as

```
val getListUdf = udf((raw: String) => raw match{
  case null => Array.empty[String]
  case _ => raw.split("\\|")
})
```

Comment: why is it "\\|"？

Comment: | (pipe) is a special character and needs to be escaped, thats why \\ is needed. Otherwise split will not work

Comment: oh,i see.Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure @秦时明月 :)

Comment: Building the logic into the UDF is a much better idea than the above accepted solution.

Comment: thanks for the comment @r0bb23 but inbuilt functions are better than udf functions as udf function would require you serialization and deserialization and are not jvm optimized.

Comment: @ramesh that can be true. But you ignore the fact that there is a udf used in both answers. It also lifts performance concerns over all other concerns. Assuming the performance hit, in this case I don't think there would be much of one if any, isn't large then programmatically having it in the udf is better. It's easier to use and harder to misuse. You don't have to worry about new people to your code base using the udf without the null filtering logic.